# Png as background inside svg shape

Tags: svg

I'm trying to create an header using a svg to generate a curved shape, like so[image]

I copied the SVG code generate from Sketch, deleted some extra tags and fixed the image path

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1440 638" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <path d="M-4.54747351e-13,163 L1440,163 L1440,700.10075 C1259.32216,751.363088 1140.10686,781.914324 1082.35411,791.754457 C776.214966,843.915606 628.837414,646.620792 362.433874,644.205808 C184.831514,642.595818 64.0202229,656.876199 6.73310296e-11,687.046952 L-4.54747351e-13,163 Z" id="path-1"></path>
    </defs>
    <g id="Header-Copy" transform="translate(0, -163.000000)">
        <mask id="mask" fill="white"><use xlink:href="#path-1"></use></mask>
        <use id="Rectangle-Copy-2" fill="#0BE17D" transform="translate(720.000000, 481.765165) scale(-1, 1) translate(-720.000000, -481.765165) " xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
        <image style="mix-blend-mode: darken;" mask="url(#mask)" x="0" y="0" width="1462.5" height="975" xlink:href="~assets/header_bg.jpg"></image>
    </g>    
</svg>
```

But I end up with this

[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: Everything disappears

Comment: There's only 1 `use` elements, there are 2 `translate` but if I delete one it still messes everything

Comment: Spelled it out in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `transform` attribute from element `<use id="Rectangle-Copy-2">`.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1440 638" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <path d="M-4.54747351e-13,163 L1440,163 L1440,700.10075 C1259.32216,751.363088 1140.10686,781.914324 1082.35411,791.754457 C776.214966,843.915606 628.837414,646.620792 362.433874,644.205808 C184.831514,642.595818 64.0202229,656.876199 6.73310296e-11,687.046952 L-4.54747351e-13,163 Z" id="path-1"></path>
    </defs>
    <g id="Header-Copy" transform="translate(0, -163.000000)">
        <mask id="mask" fill="white"><use xlink:href="#path-1"></use></mask>
        <use id="Rectangle-Copy-2" fill="#0BE17D" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
        <image style="mix-blend-mode: darken;" mask="url(#mask)" x="0" y="0" width="1462.5" height="975" xlink:href="~assets/header_bg.jpg"></image>
    </g>    
</svg>
```